# C# Chart growing outside of panel

Tags: c#, charts

My goal is to create a chart that will sit inside of a panel restricting it's size.
I managed to achieve this some time ago but today I noticed that the chart was growing inside of the panel, not allowing the data to be seen.
I have attached a picture bellow which should help understand the issue.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I noticed that if I rmeove 'bottom' from the Anchor property of the panel the chart does not exceed the parent panel but it does not increase with the change of the form which is what I'm looking for.

I also noticed that there was also another chart on the form that was exceeding the parent form, this time the chart would extend to the right not allowing to see the data.

[image: Charts growing ouside of panel]

This is the code that generates this second chart and places is inside of the parent panel.

```
  panel_chart.Controls.Clear();
            chart1 = new Chart();

            chart1.MouseMove += chart1_MouseMove;

            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("chartArea1"));
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart1.Titles.Clear();

            var serieOEE = new Series("OEE");
            serieOEE.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            serieOEE.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;

            var serieProd = new Series("Prod");
            serieProd.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            serieProd.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;

            var serieDisp = new Series("Disp");
            serieDisp.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            serieDisp.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;

            var serieQual = new Series("Qual");
            serieQual.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            serieQual.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;

            DateTime DataReg = DateTime.MinValue;
            List<AreaOEE> listaChart = new List<AreaOEE>();
            foreach (var item in ListaGrafico)  //listaOEE
            {
                if (item.Designacao == DesignacaoLista)
                {
                    listaChart.Add(item);
                }
            }
            listaChart = listaChart.OrderBy(a => a.IDReg).ToList();
            DateTime DataUltimoReg = DateTime.MinValue;
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var item in listaChart)
            {
                string HoraGraf = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Hora).ToString("HH:mm");
                if (j == 0 || j == listaChart.Count - 1 ||
                    Math.Abs(Convert.ToDateTime(item.Hora).Subtract(DataUltimoReg).TotalMinutes) >= 30)
                {
                    serieOEE.Points.AddXY(HoraGraf, item.OEE);
                    serieProd.Points.AddXY(HoraGraf, item.Produtividade);
                    serieQual.Points.AddXY(HoraGraf, item.Qualidade);
                    serieDisp.Points.AddXY(HoraGraf, item.Disponibilidade);

                    DataUltimoReg = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Hora);

                    if (j == listaChart.Count - 2)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }
            //Adicionar o ultimo
            foreach (var item in listaOEE)
            {
                if (item.Designacao == DesignacaoLista)
                {
                    string sHora = "";
                    try
                    {
                        sHora = item.Hora.Substring(1, 5);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string sEx = ex.Message;
                    }
                    foreach (var itemOee in serieOEE.Points)
                    {
                        if (itemOee.AxisLabel == sHora)
                        {
                            itemOee.YValues[0] = item.OEE;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var itemP in serieProd.Points)
                    {
                        if (itemP.AxisLabel == sHora)
                            itemP.YValues[0] = item.Produtividade;
                    }
                    foreach (var itemD in serieDisp.Points)
                    {
                        if (itemD.AxisLabel == sHora)
                            itemD.YValues[0] = item.Disponibilidade;
                    }
                    foreach (var itemQ in serieQual.Points)
                    {
                        if (itemQ.AxisLabel == sHora)
                            itemQ.YValues[0] = item.Qualidade;
                    }
                }
            }

            chart1.Series.Add(serieProd);
            chart1.Series.Add(serieQual);
            chart1.Series.Add(serieDisp);
            chart1.Series.Add(serieOEE);
            serieOEE.BorderWidth = 4;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 140;

            chart1.Legends.Clear();
            chart1.Legends.Add(serieOEE.Legend);

            chart1.Titles.Add(DesignacaoLista + "             " + DataTitulo.ToString("dd-MM HH:mm"));
            chart1.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold);
            chart1.Visible = true;
            chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            panel_chart.Controls.Add(chart1);
```

Comment: Well, it all depends on how you did set up your GUI. Unfortunately, you haven't shown any of your code that creates, initializes and utilizes your GUI with respect to the graph control. Quite probably, the container in which the graph control is "sitting" either allows the graph control to resize beyond the container's dimensions, or the container is not resizing in accordance with the size change(s) of the graph control, or perhaps something entirely else...

Comment: But enough with the speculations. Show your code (not as a screenshot! Rather, as text formatted as code block) that deals with setting up and initializing the GUI (including the graph control) of your app. If you are using UI elements from some 3rd-party libraries, it is important to also tell us also which library the UI elements are from. Otherwise, without seeing your code, there will be no cake for you...

Comment: Correct. I have added more information to explain this issue better including code

Answer (score 0):

you can change the size of Chart with `Chart.Size`:

```
Chart1.Size = new Size(1000, 200); //1000px * 200px
```